# Median confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, uniform-distribution, median

It is asked to prove that if $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from $X \sim U(\theta -1/2, \theta +1/2)$, then

$$P( \theta \in [X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}])=1-2(\frac{1}{2})^n$$

Note that $\theta$ is the median of the distribution. Before it, the problem asked to evaluate  $P(\theta \in (-\infty,X_{(n)}])$ and $ P(\theta \in [X_{(1)}, \infty))$, which are $1-(\frac{1}{2})^n,$ but I don't know how this can help.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Hint: you can rewrite all three probabilities as expectations of indicator variables. Linearity of expectation justifies the result.

Comment: Consider the *complements* of the events in the previous part and the fact that they're mutually exclusive. Now consider that the complement of the present event is the union of those two complements.

Comment: What is $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$?

Comment: @Bridgeburners That’s a notation to mean the order statistics. $X_{(j)}$ is the $j^{th}$ largest value, with $X_{(1)}$ being the smallest of all and $X_{(n)}$ being the largest of all.